# Failed to run Spark job on Yarn cluster - Retrying connect to server

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I setup my yarn cluster and also my spark cluster on the same machines but now I need to run a spark job with yarn using the client mode.

Here is my sample config for my job:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf(true).setAppName("SparkQueryApp")
             .setMaster("yarn-client")// "yarn-cluster" or "yarn-client"
             .set("es.nodes", "10.0.0.207")
             .set("es.nodes.discovery", "false")
             .set("es.cluster", "wp-es-reporting-prod")     
             .set("es.scroll.size", "5000")
            .setJars(JavaSparkContext.jarOfClass(Demo.class))
            .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
            .set("spark.default.parallelism", String.valueOf(cpus * 2))
            .set("spark.executor.memory", "10g")
            .set("spark.num.executors", "40")
            .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
            .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors", "10")
            .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", "50")              .set("spark.logConf", "true");
```

This doesn't seems to work when I tried to run my Spark job 
`java -jar spark-test-job.jar"`

I got this exception

```
405472 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to   
server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10,    
sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
406473 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to   
server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is   
RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
...
```

Any help ?

Comment: Have you tried `spark-submit` or is there any special reason why you start your jar with `java`?

Comment: @TillRohrmann Spark-submit works but is there a way to run without using the `spark-submit` ? I don't want to scp & ssh to the cluster before running or testing my job.

Comment: You can run spark-submit from your computer. Install spark to your machine. No need of scp or ssh.

Comment: spark-submit works but is there a way to just run my package spark job as `java -jar spark-job-test.jar`

Comment: why user should be limited to use spark-submit script to run spark jobs? that's ridiculous .

Comment: @AdetiloyePhilipKehinde Okay. Did spark-submit work with the same parameter? Especially executed number and memory.

Comment: @gone - spark-submit works

Comment: @AdetiloyePhilipKehinde Did you got spark-yarn got it working without spark-submit? We use mapr dist here and they said it's not possible now with newer version (post 1.2) of spark and yarn to run it like we used to. We were able to run spark as a service with spark 1.0.2 and standalone cluster. Now it's no longer possible :( I am still investigating on my side.

Comment: @nir Unfortunately no, `spark-submit` is still required for spark-yarn except in standalone